# Implementing values-v14 from Android Action Bar Style Generator

Tags: android, xml, android-resources

I am trying to style the action bar using the action bar style generator from github http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

I copied all the files into the respective folders; however I am receive multiple errors because my min sdk is 11, when 14 is required, so I have to create a values v14 folder.

[image]

The problem is that when I Override the resources in values-v14 I get this error:

[image]

Unexpected resource reference type expected value of type @style

My xml file which is generated is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<style name="Theme.Customaction" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_customaction</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Customaction</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Customaction</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Customaction</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Customaction</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Transparent.Customaction</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_customaction</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_customaction</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Customaction</item>


</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Customaction" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_customaction</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_customaction</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_customaction</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Customaction</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Customaction" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_customaction</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Customaction</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Customaction" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_customaction</item>  
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Customaction" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_customaction</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Customaction" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_customaction</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Customaction" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_customaction</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_customaction</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_customaction</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Customaction" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_customaction</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Customaction" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_customaction</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Customaction.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Customaction</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Customaction</item>
</style>
```

Not sure how to approach and fix this error

Trying to follow this http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2012/09/creating-custom-android-styles-easy-way.html

but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `Android Action Bar Style Generator`, you may forget to choose the `Style compatibility` list, the `AppCompat` item is above API 7 and `Sherlock` need a ActionBarSherlock library with your app . Its default item `holo` is not for the low Android version. May this helps.

Comment: I went with holo... what should i do?

Comment: Just have a try with AppCompat because the AppCompat works different with different platform. When the Android version is above 3.0 then system use the native library and if the Android version is below 3.0 then the system use the support library.So,just use the AppCompat.

Comment: I need to implement Holo is there any way to get around this

Comment: Yes,The AppCompat's effect is to make the app's theme like holo on the Android version below 3.0

Comment: You could just change the `Holo` to `AppCompat` to see what happened. Don't think too much. If the result is not ok, you could just undo it, very simple.